# Using Git to merge all changes from a feature branch on develop to a release branch

Tags: git, git-flow

We use GitFlow to manage our software repositories:
http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

I have a situation that I'm not sure how to handle in this branching model.

I made about a dozen commits to a `feature` branch (branched off `develop`) over the course of a couple weeks.  To reduce the burden of merging back to `develop`, I merged changes from `develop` into my `feature` branch 3 times over the course of those 2 weeks.  The `feature` branch was completed and its changes are merged back into `develop`.

However, as it turns out, this feature is also required on a `release` branch that was branched off from `develop` about a month ago.  Is there a way to merge just the changes from that old branch, but omit the changes to `develop` that I merged into it 3 times?

Comment: When pulling stuff from develop into your feature branch, you performed actual merges, rather than rebase operations?

Comment: I understand that `release` branched off `develop` *after* `release` did. Am I correct?

Comment: I merged and didn't rebase.  `Release` branched off `develop` before the new `feature` branch was branched off `develop`

Comment: @Jubobs - Where did your giant answer go that I didn't get a chance to read?

Comment: @JeffLamb I ended up deleting it, but I just undeleted it. I'm still not sure it's the best approach; on the other hand, since you're not following Git Flow, what you do to fix the problem is really up to you. You might prefer simply cherry-picking the non-merge commits on `feature` and apply them on top of `release`... Whatever you end up doing, you're likely to destabilise `release` to an extent. If I were you, I'd wait for the next release before shipping those new features :)

Comment: We're considering abandoning the release branch and creating a new one off develop to fix this issue...  I'll go over your method first, though, as soon as I get a chance to read it.

Comment: @JeffLamb Abandonning `release` and create a new release branch stemming from the tip of `develop` is the best thing to do. Good luck `:)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### According to the Git Flow model, you missed the train

Your repo must look something like that:

```
o - o - o - o - o - o [master]
 \
  \       o - o - o - o - o [release]
   \     / 
    o - o - o - o - o - o - o - o - o - o - o [develop]
                 \       \       \         /
                  o - o - o - o - o - o - o [feature]
```

However, if you and your team are indeed following the Git Flow model, I've got bad news for you: the ship has sailed. More specifically, it's too late for you to incorporate the features from your `feature` branch (now also in `develop`) into the `release` branch. That's just not allowed by Git Flow.

If you look at the following part of the main [nvie.com](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) graph, you'll see that, once a release branch is created, it's not allowed to receive anything from `develop`, let alone any feature branch. The only purpose of a release branch is stabilisation/consolidation towards the actual release, i.e. a merge into `master`.

[image]

If you really stick to the Git Flow model, you should

- either abandon the current `release` branch and create a new one stemming from the tip of `develop`,
- or freeze all work on `release` and then rebase it onto `develop` before resuming work on it,
- or wait for the next release to incorporate your new features into a release.

### If you're fine with not sticking to Git Flow...

If you're willing to go against Git Flow on this one, you can always get your features into `release` without polluting it from recent things from `develop`. The downside of the following approach is that your history will be a bit messy and will contain "duplicate commits"; but I don't think you have much of a choice if you really insist on incorporating your features from the `feature` branch into your current/active release.

For convenience, let's assume your repo looks as follows (I've labelled a few commits with letters):

```
o - o - o - o - o - o [master]
 \
  \       o - o - o - o - o [release]
   \     / 
    o - A - B - C - o - o - o - o - o - o - o [develop]
                 \       \       \         /
                  D - E - F - G - H - I - J [feature]
```

What you could do is

1. Check out `release`

   ```
   git checkout release
   ```
2. Get a list of all the revisions that were not merge commits, between commit A and the  tip of `feature`; in this case, that would be commits B, C, D, E, G, I and J. The command

   ```
   git rev-list --no-merges A..feature
   ```

   should do that for you.
3. Pass that list of revisions to `cherry-pick` in order to apply the changes introduced by those commits on top of `release`:

   ```
   git cherry-pick `git rev-list --no-merges A..feature`
   ```

   You'll end up with something like this:

   ```
   o - o - o - o - o - o [master]
    \
     \         o - o - o - o - o - B'- C'- D'- E'- G'- I'- J' [HEAD=release]
      \       /                                            
       \     /                                             
        o - A - B - C - o - o - o - o - o - o - o [develop]
                     \       \       \         /         
                      D - E - F - G - H - I - J [feature]
   ```
4. Stabilise the `release` branch.
5. Once `release` hits `master`, you should also merge it into `develop`, and you should be back on your feet.

Comment: Yes, we realize it was an oversight in the branching model.  However, this sort of thing is allowed by git.  For example, I can just `cherrypick` the commits off my `feature` branch onto a new branch off of `release`.  Then when I'm merging the changes from `release` back onto develop, if there are any conflicts, just take everything from `develop`.  I'm trying to figure out if there's a more elegant way to do it than this.

Comment: @JeffLamb You should probably wait until you see other SO users chime in and confirm that this is the best course of action to take...

Comment: For me this answer is perfect, but if there is only a few commits it could be more easy to just create a new branch in the first "feature" commit and cherry pick every commit except for merge commits. Then merge this branch to release.  (or course you will get duplicate commits)

Comment: @DaniCE See [revision 8](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25512556/8). My original approach was exactly what you describe, but I think applying those commits directly on top of `release` is comparatively simpler.

Comment: @JeffLamb Out of curiosity, what did you end up doing?

Comment: I would have likely implemented your answer.  However, we had even more scope creep introduced yesterday which required a full retest.  Therefore, we abandoned the release branch and are back on develop until all the features are implemented.  Thanks for the answer, though.

Comment: @JeffLamb Thanks for letting me know `:)` Good luck on the next release.